# Android - Stop all threads when leaving activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-activity

My app contains an `Activity` which starts a bunch of `AsyncTasks` and recursive functions. Everything works just fine - even when I leave my actitiy via the `back` or `home` button.

Is there an easy solution for just stop everything when leaving the activity?

**Edit**

My background threads make http calls etc. Via my logs I can see that the threads are still running.

Comment: In theory, Android already takes care of that for you.

Comment: No it doesn't. else I wouldn't ask about it, right? ;)

Comment: Try with `System.exit()`. This will make sure the process is destroyed (and hence all attached threads). Oh and *threads are not processes*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to cancel all background threads.

OnStop or onDistroy of your activity you need to call below method to stop AsyncTask.

```
asyncTask.stop(boolean)
```

Well, it will not directly stop you asyncTask but in doInBackground method you need to keep on checking for [isCancelled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29) value, if its true then just end the doInBackground and skip postExecute for appropriate return value in status. This is the only way in my knowledge.

Comment: is `OnStop` and `OnDestroy` covering all the possibilities of leaving the Activity?

Comment: I used a global variable now but stuck to your basic idea. thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You can override onPause() in the activity to stop the threads.

So you can do:

```
@Override    
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause()
    // Stop threads here
}
```

And recreate them in onResume().